# Что такое d в числе 500d при присваивании значения переменной типа double?

Tags: c#

Генерим животное через кортеж - вид животного, максимальный возраст, максимальный вес

```cs
private static (string Breed,int MaxAge,double MaxWeight)[] _breeds=
{
    ("птица",    30,    20.5),
    ("бык",      30,    500d)
    //...
}
```

Что такое `d`? И почему у птицы такого значения нет?

Comment: Вы определитесь уж. В заголовке "Измерение максимального веса", в вопросе "генерируем кортеж", а далее вопрос "что такое `d`?". Ок, а как **что такое d** относится к **кортеж**, ведь с таким же успехом вы могли показать нам `double MaxWeight = 500d;`, без всяких птиц, кортежей, всяких "измерений веса" и другой ерунды.

Comment: [Числовые типы с плавающей запятой (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Comment: Исправил заголовок, чтобы он лучше отражал суть вопроса.